# count a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know that how can I count elements in a column of dataframe and know what element has the highest count?

For example, I have this dataframe:

```
    sample     target
0      a       0
1      b       0
2      c       0
3      d       1
4      e       1
5      f       1
6      g       0
```

At the first step, I have to count target column: I want something that give me how many `0` or `1` is in target column and at the next step I want to know what target has the greater amount of count.
In this example the answer is `0`,
my question is how can I get the true target. In this case, I need a code to give me `0` as the greatest amount of count for target column.

Comment: i'm so sorry, the dataframe is: pd.DataFrame({'sample':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],'target':[0,0,0,1,1,1,0]})

Comment: See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` in pandas

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'sample':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],'target':[0,0,0,1,1,1,0]})
>>> df.groupby(['target']).count()
        sample
target
0            4
1            3
>>>
```

If you want to get the max you can use `max()` function on the grouped dataframe. Or if you want to get the index(target in your case) you can use `idxmax()` function.

Comment: thank you very much brother, its working very well.

Comment: @LMKR from my experience it helps if add a comment  saying please accept if it helps for you just after adding the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you are **just** interested in the working with the `target` column. In that case, you can simply use [`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) method:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'sample':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],'target':[0,0,0,1,1,1,0]}) 

>>> df
  sample  target
0      a       0
1      b       0
2      c       0
3      d       1
4      e       1
5      f       1
6      g       0

>>> df['target'].value_counts(ascending=False)
#output
0    4
1    3
Name: target, dtype: int64

#find the target class with max count
>>> df['target'].value_counts(ascending=False).index[0]
0

#find the max count
>>> df['target'].value_counts(ascending=False).max()
4
```

**This method is not gonna work if you want to find max counts within samples. In that case, `groupby` method.**